# I get errors in the source code of underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, adobe-brackets, underscore.js-templating

I am new to underscore.js . I am using the brackets IDE and when I copy and paste the source code from GITHUB in a file name underscore.js in my local directory to use it in my page and save it , it shows errors...I have attached the screen shot of the errors below..

[image]

Comment: They're JSLint errors, not JavaScript errors........

Comment: in other words, the code will run but if you fix those JSLint errors as well your code will be a bit better.

Comment: The code will not necessarily be better if you 'fix' it. Underscore is using EsLint and it's probably configured differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not real errors just JSLint/JSHint errors. They are just static code analiyzer. Just ignore it to have checked by JSLint and everything will be just fine.

JSLint:
http://www.jslint.com/help.html